# Nestjs incorrent dist folder structure with monorepo mode

Tags: nestjs

How come it generates dist/apps/twitter and puts everything into this folder must be put just into dist folder? What can lead to this?

[image]

Expected dist folder structure:

```
dist:
--apps:
----twitter/src
--libs
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "incorrect" per se. When Nest is in monorepo mode, it by default will use `webpack` to bundle the application code together to a single file. This of course can be overridden and `tsc` can be used instead to output all of the compiled TS code if that is preferred. When `tsc` compiles code that contains sources outside of a single directory (e.g. `apps/twitter/src` is the base directory but `libs/whatever` is imported as well) then Typescript does its best to maintain the directory structure in the resulting `dist` so that import paths do not end up getting messed up.

The reason for having the `apps/twitter` twice is because Nest sets the output directory of the `build` to be `dist/apps/<app-name>`, similarly to how Nx does. This is done so that if you end up having multiple applications, say `apps/google`, you can have`dist/apps/twitter` and `dist/apps/google` and not have their dists interfere with each other

Comment: So, I have *.d.ts file with some typings included both in tsconfig.lib.json and tsconfig.app.json. For some reason, tsc cannot find some declaration of type used in lib if d.ts file not icludeded in tsconfig.app.ts (the including the d.ts file in tsconfig.lib.json doesn't matter for tsc). Then I gains dist folder structure presented above. But if I don't use types from d.ts file in library I gain expected dist folder structure and I don't realize why lib depends on d.ts file including in tsconfig.app.json, not in tsconfig.lib.json.